Local changes uncontrollably when the page changes
I am using "next-intl": "^3.17.2" in my project. There is no problem with my language change switch. However, when I change the page by clicking on the links in the Navbar, the local language changes uncontrollably, why? Thanks.
i18.ts
import {notFound} from 'next/navigation';
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';
import { Locale, locales } from 'lib/locales';

export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => {
    const baseLocale = new Intl.Locale(locale).baseName as Locale;
    if (!locales.includes(baseLocale)) notFound();
    return {
        messages: (await import(`./messages/${locale}.json`)).default
    };
});

middleware.ts
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';
 
export default createMiddleware({
  locales: ['de', 'en'],
  defaultLocale: 'en'
});

export const config = {
    matcher : ['/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)' , '/' , '/(en|de)/:path*'],
}

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
  params: {locale}
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  params: {locale: string};
}) {

  const messages = await getMessages();
  return (
    <html lang={locale} className="light">
      <body className="bg-neutral-200 selection:bg-yellow-400 selection:text-neutral-700 dark:bg-neutral-800">
      <Background /> 
       <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages}>
          <Providers>
            <>
              <div className="mx-auto max-w-screen-2xl px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                <Navbar />
                <main>
                  {children}
                </main>
              </div>
            <Footer />
            </>
          </Providers>
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

I expect the local language and locale in the URL not to change uncontrollably when the page changes.

may i see a Link component in  ? .You might use Link component from 'next/link'
which you cause you to uncontrolled current locale from next-intl. you have to use Link component that imported from 'next-intl' instead
my suggestion you can create core naviagation file and use Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter
// @/config/navigation
import { createSharedPathnamesNavigation } from 'next-intl/navigation';

import { locales } from '@/i18n/config';

export const { Link, redirect, usePathname, useRouter } =
  createSharedPathnamesNavigation({
    locales: locales.map(locale => locale.key),
    localePrefix: 'as-needed'
  });

which is @/i18n/config contain these code
import { getRequestConfig } from 'next-intl/server';

export default getRequestConfig(async ({ locale }) => ({
  timeZone: 'Asia/Bangkok',
  messages: (await import(`./${locale}.json`)).default
}));

export const locales = [
  {
    key: 'en',
    title: 'English'
  },
  {
    key: 'th',
    title: 'ไทย'
  }
];

export const defaultIntlLocale = 'th';

so when you when you want to use Link component just import it from first file (@/config/navigation) or even you want to programatic route with current locale just import useRouter, redirect, usePathname from the file which is give you routing with a current locale in website as well
hope it help !
